# How to prevent freezing while waiting to load google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In this example I have implemented a google map in a fragment. This app also has a navigation drawer. In the navigation drawer there is a list view which acts as a menu for the app. The menu items are "map" and "Fragment 1". When I select "map" from the navigation drawer the screen freezes for like two seconds and after that the navigation drawer slides back and the map is loaded. This is bad for user experience. Are there any ways of preventing the app from freezing in this situation? A way to allow the navigation drawer to function normally and indicate user's map is still loading? Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private FrameLayout framlaout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        framlaout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        toolbar.setTitle("example");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationFragment navigationFragment = (NavigationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_fragment);
        navigationFragment.setupNavigationProperty(R.id.navigation_fragment,drawerLayout,toolbar);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new BlankFragment()).commit();

    }
```

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

NavigationFragment.java

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {


    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> menuItems;
    private View containerView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    public NavigationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);

        initComponents(view);
        onClickItemnListnener();

        return view;
    }

    public void initComponents(View view){
        menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
        menuItems.add("Fragment 1");
        menuItems.add("map");

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuItems));
    }

    public void setupNavigationProperty(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar){
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar
                ,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickItemnListnener(){
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (menuItems.get(position)){
                    case "Fragment 1":
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new BlankFragment()).commit();
                        closeNavigationDrawer(drawerLayout,containerView);
                        break;
                    case "map":
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new MapFragment()).commit();
                        closeNavigationDrawer(drawerLayout,containerView);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void closeNavigationDrawer(DrawerLayout layout,View fragmentView){
        drawerLayout = layout;
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
    }
```

"Fragment 1" is a empty fragment.

I did something like this But same result.

```
final SupportMapFragment[] mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment[1];

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mapFragment[0] = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            }
        };
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            thread.join();
            mapFragment[0].getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private FrameLayout framlaout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        framlaout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        toolbar.setTitle("example");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationFragment navigationFragment = (NavigationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_fragment);
        navigationFragment.setupNavigationProperty(R.id.navigation_fragment,drawerLayout,toolbar);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new BlankFragment()).commit();

}
```

MapFragment.java

Comment: You haven't change any thing ?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using SupportMapFragment you should probably use the MapView class directly. Unfortunately even if Google calls the loading of the map "asynch" it actually runs in the UI thread, and thats what causes the freezing.

What helped me is to run this in a background thread the first time the application starts, it preloads the mapview basically:

```
Runnable initMap = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MapView mapView = new MapView(YourActivity.this);
            mapView.onCreate(null);
        }
    };
    new Thread(initMap).start();
```

Comment: that didn't work same results. I cant call getMapAsync(this); on thread. it has to be call in main Thread.